# $(g,f)_{L^2} \le C||g||_{H^{-s}}||f||_{H^s}$ right or wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am proving something, and I may need the following inequality:
$$
(g,f)_{L^2} \le C||g||_{H^{-s}}||f||_{H^s}
$$
where $(g,f)_{L^2} $ is inner product and $f$ and $g$ have higher enough regularity and $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

I think I can prove it and it is very easy. I don't know if it is right and where I can find a book referring to it (because I think this inequality would very useful and should be mentioned in some book). Anyway, I will put my proof here, I hope someone could check it and tell me where I can find it (there might be some other obvious reasons for it, if so, I hope you can tell me. I feel a little bit dizzy now due to the whole day study and work, perhaps I just miss some obvious facts).

I put all the constant into $C$.

Proof: 
$$
(g,f)_{L^2} =C \int_\mathbb{R}\hat{g}(\zeta)\hat{f}(\zeta)d\zeta=C \int_\mathbb{R}\hat{g}(\zeta)(1+|\zeta|^2)^{-s/2}\hat{f}(\zeta)(1+|\zeta|^2)^{s/2}d\zeta \le C(\int_\mathbb{R}|\hat{g}(\zeta)|^2(1+|\zeta|^2)^{-s} d\zeta)^{1/2} (\int_\mathbb{R}|\hat{f}(\zeta)|^2(1+|\zeta|^2)^{s} d\zeta )^{1/2} \le C||g||_{H^{-s}}||f||_{H^s} 
$$

Comment: Your argument is correct.  But some people define $H^{-s}$ as the dual space to $H^s$, so in that sense the result you want is actually true by definition of $H^{-s}$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Oh, yes. You are right, I forgot the duality, so it is actually obvious. Thanks a lot.